# How to mock a method that is not in the scope of a test?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mocking

#### How to mock a method that is not in the scope of a test?

**or:** How to mock a method that is not called directly?

In this case method **baz**
I'm using the [Mock package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) from pypi

```
### tests
# ...
def test_method_a(self):
    # how to mock method that is called from bar() ?
    obj = foo.bar()
    self.assertEqual(obj.get('x'), 12345)

### foo
# ...
def bar():
    x = some_module.baz()  # <- how to mock baz() ?
    return x
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example that should show you how it works:

```
from mock import patch

def baz():
  return 'y'


def bar():
  x = baz()  # <- how to mock baz() ?
  return x


def test():
  with patch('__main__.baz') as baz_mock:
    baz_mock.return_value = 'blah'
    assert bar() == 'blah'
test()
```

Comment: uhm.. can you add some explanation? Either I do not understand your example or it is not working

Comment: Whoops, I did have a small error. I confirmed this works on my machine. Hope this helps.

Comment: cool, this one works! Can you explain how to mock many methods with a single patch? (without nested `with` statements) `patch('module') as mock: mock.baz.return_value # ...` is not working :/

Comment: @Lucas, if all the methods you need to patch are on a single object, you can use [`patch.multiple`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#patch-multiple).

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this example better illustrates the common use case during unit testing.

The important part is the `@patch` decorator which effectively substitutes the `side_effect` function (this could also just be a value) for the function being patched. The tricky bit is often getting the full package path to the patched function. Notice how you must use `'__main__.func'` to reference the patched function.

The first test, `test_func` checks that the mocked value of the test is the original expected function value (`'Hello World!'`). The second test, `test_mocked_func` patches `func` to actually be the function object `new_func`, hence returning `True`. The third test illustrates substituting in values rather than a new function as the `side_effect`. In fact, since we made the substitution value an iterable (`side_effect=['New String 1!', 'New String 2!', 3]`), each time it runs, it will return a new value.

*Warning: If you try to call your patched function more times than you have specified return values (3 in this case), you will get a `StopIteration` error since you didn't define enough return values in `side_effect`.*

```
import unittest
from mock import patch # for Python 2.7
# from unittest.mock import patch # for Python 3.5

def func():
    return 'Hello World!'

def newFunc():
    return True

class TestFunc(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_func(self):
        self.assertEqual(func(), 'Hello World!')

    @patch('__main__.func', side_effect=newFunc)
    def test_mocked_func(self, *patches):
        self.assertTrue(func())

    @patch('__main__.func', side_effect=['New String 1!', 'New String 2!', 3])
    def test_mocked_func_again(self, *patches):
        self.assertEqual(func(), 'New String 1!')
        self.assertEqual(func(), 'New String 2!')
        self.assertEqual(func(), 3)
        # func() # This breaks the test because we only specified a list of length 3 in our patch.

if __name__=='__main__':
    unittest.main()
```